# Defining enumerations and constants locally in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

I would like to define enumerations and constants locally within the scope of a function.

I saw that MATLAB provides enumerations and constants as part of its object-oriented programming framework. However, if you try to define them within the scope of a function, they don't work. E.g. MATLAB complains with "Parse error: invalid syntax" if you try the following:

```
function output = my_function(input)

classdef my_constants
  properties (Constant)
    x = 0.2;
    y = 0.4;
    z = 0.5;
  end
end

classdef colors
  enumeration
    blue, red
  end
end

statements;
```

The reason seems to be that each `classdef` needs to defined in its own`.m` file.

I would like to avoid having an `.m` file for every enumeration or set of constants that I use. Is there a way to do this? What are my options?

### Addendum 1:

Sine I was asked for an example, here's one in **pseudocode**. This example depicts my need for defining and using local enumerations.

Say I have an enumeration type called `colors` that can  be `RED` or `BLUE`. I would like to define `colors` locally in my function, and use it do control the flow of my statements in the function:

```
function output = my_function(input)

# ....
# Code that defines the enumeration 'colors'
#....

my_color = colors;

# ... code that changes 'my_color' ...

switch my_color
   case RED
       do this
   case BLUE
       do that;

end
```

### Addendum 2:

Could I do this by leveraging Java code? If so, how?

Comment: Could you post an example of what you would like to have?

Answer (score 1):

I think enumerations would be overkill.  You can do this by

- defining a matlab struct of RGB values
- determine which color is "inputted" and remembering that color fieldname
- do something with that color

  ```
  function output = my_function(input)

  % Code that defines the enumeration 'colors' in terms of RGB

  colors.RED = [1 0 0];
  colors.BLUE = [0 0 1]

  ... etc ... 



  % ... here... what determine my_color is, 
  % which is logic specific to your function
  % 
  % You should assign 'my_color' to the same struct
  % fieldname used in the above 'colors' 

  if( some red conditon )

     my_color = 'RED';

  elseif( some blue condition)
     my_color = 'BLUE';

  elseif(etc...)

  end


  % at this point, my_color will be a fieldname 
  % of the 'colors' struct.
  % 
  % You are able to dynamically extract the 
  % RGB value from the 'colors' struct using 
  % what is called called dynamic field reference.
  %
  % This means...
  % 
  % While you can hardcode blue like this:
  %
  %   colorsStruct.BLUE
  %
  % You are also able to dynamically get BLUE like this: 
  %
  %   colorName = 'BLUE';
  %   rgbValue = colorsStruct.(colorName);
  % 
  %
  % Loren has a good blog on this:
  %
  %   http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/



  % Extract the rgb value
  my_color_rgb_value = colors.(my_color);


  % Do something with the RGB value
  your_specific_function(my_color_rgb_value);


  end
  ```

Hope this helps.  Please post a follow up if not.